# Paste as image adding extra padding inside image

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

So whenever I am doing a 'paste as image' from excel table to word or outlook, the table image is given extra padding both beneath and to the right. I used to be able to copy images flush with one another, but with the extra space inside the image (not a paragraph or extra space in word, Outlook, or OnoNote) the images aren't right anymore.

For instance, instead of an image being 4 in wide, 3 inches tall, the image is 3 inches wide with an inch of whitespace, and 2.5 inches tall with an extra half inch of whitespace

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Office?

Comment: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013

Answer (score 0):

Padding is applied in the source application. Remove styles after pasting or use the paste options to keep the source formatting. After pasting, check the paragraph settings and remove spacing before/after and set line spacing to single.

You may want to create a style with none of these padding effects and apply the style after pasting the image.

Also, take a look at the text wrapping and position settings in the layout options of the picture tools.

Comment: So I have always been able to paste correctly keeping source formatting, but I want this as an image for easy scaling. My coworkers (who mostly use Office 2010), don't have this problem while accessing the same document.

I should reiterate that this isn't a format in Word/OneNote problem. It isn't adding space to the document. The actual imported image has white space not in the excel table to the right and beneath

Comment: I can't repro that. Please post a screenshot of the problem. Think file sharing service and post a link. Edit your question and post the link there.